# Set a website as win10(or macos) desktop

Tags: macos, windows-10, desktop, website

Is there a way to set a certain website as win10/macos desktop and can it update itself every x hours(or minutes)?

Comment: Why not just run a browser maybe in fullscreen? I don't think its a default feature for Windows 10 anymore.

Comment: My original intention is that I sometimes forget to check some websites for updates. And if I make it my desktop, I will see it every time I go back to my desktop... And it's also fun : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This used to be an in-built feature of Windows 98 called **Active Desktop**. It was still available on Windows XP, but dropped after that.

Searching for "Active Desktop Windows 10" gives a lot of solutions, but most of the results are much the same what as a full-screen browser would achieve: they overlay the desktop and therefore hide the desktop icons.

The most promising seems to be [this](https://pulsar-technologies.com/ActiveDesktop/public/#screen1), though it does need logging into external cloud servers in order to maintain updating.

If you don't want to use third-party software, the best you can do is to split your screen into two areas. On a vertical split, the left part would expose your desktop and in the right part you would fill the area with a non-default browser displaying the web page you require.

This would give you live information you want while still allowing you the normal facilities of your desktop, and would have the advantage that information would never be obscured by the desktop icons.

Note that some browsers have more control than others over borders, headers and controls external to the web page when not in full-screen.

Finally, you might like to consider whether an active screen-saver (like [this](http://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/25/windows-10/set-webpage-screensaver-windows-10.html), for instance) would suit your requirements.

Comment: Although the searching of "Active Desktop Windows 10" didn't provide me a good solution, the active screen-saver is really a good idea for reminding. So I may try this way instead of changing my desktop if I still can't find better solutions for active desktop.

Answer (score 0):

A simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=set%20website%20as%20desktop%20background%20windows%2010&oq=set%20a%20website%20as%20background%20windows%201&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.8741j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) gives you plenty of options.

[WallPaperWebPage](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/WallpaperWebPage.shtml) appears to be a popular option.

Comment: WallPaperWebPage will hide desktop icons. And what I want is just a 'background desktop'. It is also OK if I can't interact with the website.